# VBA - Select the first 2 values of a slicer

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to select the two first values of a slicer using VBA.

For now, my code is as follow:

```
ActiveSheet.SlicerCaches("EXAMPLE").ClearAllFilters
cnt = .SlicerItems.Count
If cnt > 2 Then
    For i = 3 To cnt
        .SlicerItems(i).Selected = False
    Next
End If
End With
```

Could you please help me on that ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Slicer is in the ActiveWorkbook (replace `ActiveWorkbook` with a reference to the specific Workbook otherwise) and the Slicer is named "EXAMPLE", then use:

```
Dim i As Long
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("EXAMPLE")
    .ClearAllFilters
    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
        .SlicerItems(i).Selected = i <= 2
    Next i
End With
```